# Short Erlang function to demonstrate hd and tl

Tags: erlang

I'm simultaneously learning Erlang and writing a short guide on list operations. Here is a trivial function I wrote to demonstrate hd and tl:

```
headAndTail(List) ->
  Head = hd(List),
  Tail = tl(List),
  {Head, Tail}.
```

This works, but it throws "Warning: variable 'Head' is unused." I know this function could be written with `{hd(List), tl(List)}`, but is the way I did it considered bad practice?

Comment: Are you certain that's the actual code? The compiler produces such warnings when you really don't use a variable anywhere, but here you clearly do so in the return value...

Comment: Yep, I'm certain.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code sample does **not** produce warnings under the Erlang compiler (I'm almost certain that specific version does not matter).

```
$ cat bar.erl
-module(bar).

-export([headAndTail/1]).

headAndTail(List) ->
  Head = hd(List),
  Tail = tl(List),
  {Head, Tail}.

$ erlc bar.erl 
$
```

---

Now, regarding bad practises, the only comment is that what you are trying to do with `hd` and `tl` is usually done with pattern matching in functional programming languages:

```
headAndTail([Head|Tail]) ->
    {Head, Tail}.
```

Another minor bad practise is that Erlang's common naming convention does not use [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for function names, preferring `names_with_underscores` instead. CamelCase is ok for variables.